# Get data from SharePoint and push it into a java application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

what would i need to do to get the data from share point and push it to the application which is written in java? unfortunately i have just little info about the task at this time... also to achieve this task what all expertise is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing more, I'd direct you to have your java app pull data via [SharePoint Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx) or the new [REST Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521587.aspx) introduced in SharePoint 2010

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your reply - should i know java inorder to achieve this task?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot say what you will need to learn without additional information on the architecture you are working with.  However, to have Java pull the data, then yes you would need to know java.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable solution will be as Dave suggested to use SharePoint web services to get data out of sharepoint into Java application, You probably need to have knowledge about XML to read data returned by SharePoint webservices,

this following link will help you I guess :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314258/how-do-i-upload-a-document-to-sharepoint-with-java

Answer (score 0):

If it is important to push data from SharePoint instead of pulling, you could do something similar to what Dave said, just the other way around; Call a Java web service from SharePoint.

1. Create a [web service in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900425).
2. Create an [Event Receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms437502.aspx) in SharePoint.
3. Add your Java web service to your [Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) for the Event Receiver.
4. Call the service.